# IDataReader Unity + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a Unity project (version 2019) + SQLite + VSCode.
I added the appropriate plugins in the project folder but I still have the following error:

```
 Assets \ BancoSQLite.cs (33,17): error CS0433: The type 'IDataReader' exists in both 'System.Data, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089' and 'netstandard, Version =
2.0.0.0.0 , Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 '
```

I did everything but I can't come up with a solution.

**Script SQLite**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class BancoSQLite : MonoBehaviour {
//private IDbConnection connection;
//private IDbCommand command;
//private IDataReader reader;


public InputField ifLogin;
public InputField ifSenha;
public string senha;
public string login;

private string dbName = "URI=file:SQLiteDB.db";

private void Connection () {
    Debug.Log("Entrou");
    using (var connection = new SqliteConnection (dbName)) {
        connection.Open ();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
            connection.Open ();

            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, login VARCHAR(30), senha VARCHAR(30));";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            command.CommandText = "SELECT " + ifLogin + " FROM usuario;";
            //IDataReader login = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            
            Debug.Log(login);
        }
    }
}




// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start () {
    Connection ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

None of this is for the specific issue in the question, but when you solve that the code *will* run into these things, too:

`select ifLogin from usario` is wrong. You need `select * from usuario where login = ifLogin`. And make sure to use parameterized queries; sooner or later string concatenation for this **WILL** break your database.

Additionally, if you want to see the results use `ExecuteReader()`, `ExecuteScalar()`, or `Fill()` a dataset/table. `ExecuteNonQuery()` is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and doesn't give you results for SELECT.